# tcp relay server using the same port

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, network-programming

Here is the situation. I want to replay the traffic coming from one client to another client. These clients are connected to the server using the same port. To be more specific, I want to stream data from a client to another while the server is acting like a network switch. The sending client is sending music stream so that it is essential that the server relays the stream without writing into files.
 I wonder if I can implement this using TCP without writing into files?
and I am using Java for it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, just listen at the port, accept both connections, and copy between them in both directions simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that. Both clients will connect with the server, the server when receives the data from `recv()` will call `send()` for the other client. You can use the same buffer that will be used with `recv()` and `send().`